# TeX engine can't write on hidden aux files in Windows

Tags: miktex, windows, auxiliary-files, write

To make my latex folder clean, I tried to hide all auxiliary files with the following DOS command:

```
attrib +S +H *.aux
......
attrib +S +H *.toc
```

But when I tried to compile my latex file again, `xelatex` and `pdflatex` in MiKTeX threw the following error:

```
I can't write on file `somename.aux'.
```

Is it possible to enable `xelatex` and `pdflatex` to write on auxiliary files, while these files remain hidden?

BTW: I don't want to put auxiliary files to other folder, since this way causes other problems.

Comment: Did you try without `+S`? `+S` sets the `system file` attribut, perhaps only writable/removable if the application (in this case `TeX`) is run by the administrator or has administrator rights, which is probably not true when you run MikTeX as normal user. I can not test my proposition since I do not work on Windows, its just a remembrance back to 1996, when I used DOS commands for the last time, before switching to Linux ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Actually, I tried without `+S`, and the result was the same.

Comment: Did you check whether the hidden `*.aux` etc. files are writable at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I opened one `.aux` file with text editor, modified and saved it. No problem.

Comment: @ZH: I can only imagine, that the `Hidden` flag prevents that `TeX` can find your files at all?

Comment: I find the same problem in Linux http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198629/is-it-possible-to-compile-hidden-files

Comment: The solution (in Linux/TeXLive) involves editing `texmf.cnf` http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198631/1871 . There must be an equivalent file in MikTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Windows hidden files can only be opened in read/write or append mode and not in plain write mode. Oddly I can't seem to find much official documentation on this, but you can test this yourself with code or a simple cmd.exe script (which I ran on Windows 8.1):

```
C:\>echo "hello" > temp.aux
C:\>attrib +H temp.aux
C:\>echo "hello" >> temp.aux
C:\>echo "hello" > temp.aux
Access is denied.
```

Using Procmon.exe one can see that the error is when `pdflatex` tries to open the .aux file in write mode. Other programs have this problem as well (I think wordpad, and the GitHub client with .gitignore/.gitattributes files that are hidden).

Your best bet is to wrap the PDF compilation call with hide and unhide calls in a script.