# How to set the interactive editor in TeXLive? lualatex bug?

Tags: luatex, compiling, editors, bugs

> After some research we determined this is a problem inherent to
>   `lualatex`.  If you have a solution for this problem in LuaLaTeX please
>   post it below and I will accept you answer.

When compiling a file with LaTeX (and others), if there is an error one has the option to edit the file at the line of the error (or near) by pressing `e + Enter`.

For example, if one has this file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\badcommand
\end{document}
```

I get this

```
...
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./main.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \badcommand
?
```

However, in my current configuration TeXLive 2015 (Fedora), nothing happens.
I only get this message:

```
You want to edit file ./main.tex at line 81
 297 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 rule, 48 glue_spec, 1 write, 1 dir, 1 pdf_colorstack nodes
   avail lists: 2:12,3:1,6:2,9:1
No pages of output.
Transcript written on document.log.
prompt $_
```

How can I configure the editor? in particular `Gedit`.

(I am suspecting it tries to open `emacs` which is not installed, but still I would like to use `Gedit` instead).

Comment: On a unix-like system, including macosx, just set the `TEXEDIT` environment variable in your shell (e.g. in the appropriate one of .bashrc, .bash_profile, .cshrc, .zshrc etc). For example, I have `export TEXEDIT="/usr/bin/gvim +%d %s"` in .bash_profile.

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe there is some security option that disables execution from LaTeX.

Comment: You need to source the file or restart your shell before it takes effect.

Comment: It probably tries to open `vi`. At least, that's what upstream's TeX does by default. I don't use Fedora's TL packages (even though I use Fedora on one machine), but I can't especially see why they'd change it to `emacs`.

Comment: @Andrew, I did that, also `export TEXEDIT=...` before running LaTeX.

Comment: @cfr, I said `emacs` because, contrary to `emacs`, `vi` was installed and LaTeX didn't call any program after `e`. I think it is not working from any program.

Comment: It is `vi` in upstream's configuration - it is hard-coded in `texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` which sets the installation's default. (But you shouldn't edit this file or try to change the value here. Instead, you use the local `texmf.cnf` which, for upstream, is at the root of the TeX installation, normally, `/usr/local/texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf`. If it tries to use `emacs` on your system, I guess Fedora change the default.

Comment: Note that it seems to think the error is in `color.cfg`. If so, it will fail because you can't edit that file as you don't have permission. In reality, that is not where the error is, but the compiler is not always able to work this out. Try with a simple example with a simple syntax error such that TeX clearly knows that the error is in your `.tex` file.

Comment: @Andrew, your solution worked but only with `pdflatex` and not with `lualatex`. It seems that `lualatex` has some additional security measure.

Comment: Well, there's a first time for everything ;). Generally LuaTeX is much *less* secure.

Comment: Have you looked through `web2c/texmfcnf.lua`? Near the end, it says, `-- In an edit cycle it can be handy to launch an editor. The
            -- preferred one can be set here.` but then it gives no indication ***how*** to set it. The next line concerns the PDF viewer and the previous one the OTF font loader.

Comment: @cfr, 1) perhaps we can guess the name of the option. `["editor.method"]`? (also 2) It would be interesting to know how luatex can benefit from know the PDF viewer, `["pdfview.method"]           = "okular", `

Comment: The trouble is I know absolutely nothing about Lua. But `editor.method` seems a reasonable guess. See if you can copy the configuration file to your working directory and have `kpsewhich` recognise it. If so, you can play around with it safely for testing purposes rather than messing around modifying the original. I'm also not sure if we're really meant to modify that file or not. It seems to *say* to, but won't it get overwritten on update? I expected an equivalent of the `texmf.cnf` strategy i.e. a separate file for local customisations.

Comment: Although this file seems to be only for ConTeXt ... But doesn't `context` call `luatex` ... ? There is a custom version of the file in the same directory as the custom `texmf.cnf`. And ConTeXt reads it. But LuaTeX doesn't seem to read anything ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are happy setting this system wide, you can edit the customisation into `texmf.cnf` but it is important to pick the *correct* `texmf.cnf`. Probably `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` should return the correct file. On my system, for TeX Live 2015, this is `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf.cnf`. Wherever it is, the file should be almost empty with just some explanatory comments at the top. Here's mine after adding the configuration line for the editor:

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
TEXEDIT = /usr/bin/vim +%d '%s'
```

You will need to add an appropriately modified

```
TEXEDIT = /usr/bin/vim +%d '%s'
```

to your file, as I just added this line to mine. After doing so, I can edit the file using `e`.

I am not sure why the default is not to use the system or user value of `EDITOR`. TeX simply ignores this on my system and tries to use an editor which doesn't exist, with inevitably unsatisfactory results. What it should do is use `EDITOR` if that's configured, but I can't even get the file to use the value of a shell variable, so probably this is a hopeless enterprise. Hence, I hard-coded it as shown above, which does work even though the solution is not really a satisfying one.

Comment: Thanks, but I put `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`which gives `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf`, edit the file and put line `TEXEDIT = gedit +%d '%s'` around line 656. Still it does nothing after I press `e + Enter`. Same thing happens with setting the environment variable. (also I have no `/usr/local/texlive`)

Comment: Editing that file isn't good. As I said, the file should be almost empty. I assume you're using your distro's packages for TeX Live and that complicates things. Apparently, they do not include the empty-but-for-comments copy of `texmf.cnf` which upstream provide. Probably you'd have to create it. (Maybe in `/etc`.) But likely the environment variable is a better option in this case. Try it first with a command-line editor to rule out issues opening an X11 window.

Comment: `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` should be fine. It worked in the past for other options: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198631/1871

Comment: The way TeX Live is currently configured, local changes are supposed to go into a *different* `texmf.cnf` file. Unless Fedora have changed this, you shouldn't put your changes into that file.

Comment: Read the comments at the top of the file you are editing. ***It tells you explicitly not to make changes here.*** Nothing terrible will happen, but your changes will be lost when your installation is updated. The same was true for the 2014 edition. Again, these files tell you where to make changes - and where not to - quite explicitly.

Comment: ok, I think the problem is that I was using lualatex and not pdflatex. It is lualatex that has problems opening the file.

Comment: @alfC You're right. Same here. I don't think it is security: I think it is probably a bug. As you probably know, LuaTeX is much buggier, in general, than pdfTeX because it is changing a lot more. (Well, that's one reason. There are others....) The bug might be the text message - i.e. it isn't meant to offer the option - or it might be the behaviour - i.e. it is supposed to honour the option.