# How to change the default editor for interactive editing in LaTeX, etc. to Notepad++

Tags: texlive, editors

I am running a file in LaTeX (through TeX Live with Notepad++ editor) it is having error; when I am entering the errorstopmode `e` on the console the TeX file is not opening in the editor, but I want to open in NotePad++ to the error line, 
how to change the default editor from LaTeX?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305062/how-to-set-the-interactive-editor-in-texlive-lualatex-bug perhaps?

Comment: For example, on Windows if I do `set TEXEDIT=texworks --position=+%d "%s`, I get TeXworks opening as requested

Comment: @Joseph Wright, I had tried, and changed to ``notepad++`` in the ``TEXEDIT `` its creating a new file ``-position=+4" and opening this file in the notepadd++, not going in the compiled file

Comment: I guess you need to know what the right arguments are for Notepad++: that's off-topic here ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `TEXEDIT`, either in `texmf.cnf` or perhaps easier by setting the appropriate environmental variable. The latter can be done for testing at the command line

```
set TEXEDIT="<path>\notepad++.exe" -n%d %s
```

then fixed more permanently using the Control Panel.